# move to completion instantly if no animations affected

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, duration

I'm using 
`UIView.animated(withDuration:animations:completion:)` function and there are sometimes that there is no animations affected in the animations block

For example:

Let's assume that I have a `view`, and it's `frame.origin.y` is already equals to 0.

Now the animation that I wan't to make is that:

```swift
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 1,
    animations: {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
    completion: { completed in
        guard completed else { return }
        // do something
    }
)
```

The completion block called after 1 second instead of instantly.

How can I make that the completion block will called instantly if there are no animations affected in the animations block without any duration.

Comment: Technically I believe there is still an animation if you assign to an animatable property even if the animation is unnoticeable to the user, so just because `origin.y` was already `0` doesn't mean there wouldn't be an animation. You need to check for this case yourself and just not animate.

Answer (score 2):

This is a something that you should handle yourself , the `animations` won't know that , you can make a compare like

```
 if self.view.frame.origin.y != someValue {
    // do animation
 }
 else {
    // run some other code
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
withDuration: 1,
```

With

```
withDuration: 0.01,
```

(Or even less)

Comment: the problem is not limited to 0 it's for any equal value , so this won't solve it when the assigned `y` is not equal to  `self.view.frame.origin.y ` assumging a static value for `y` is meaningless as there will be no animation at all